# echo message is append with spaces

Tags: php

on login success echo message is append with spaces

```
<?php
include "dbconn.php";
if((isset($_REQUEST['email'])) && (!empty($_REQUEST['password'])))
{
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$check ="select * from register_unity where email='".$_REQUEST['email']."' and password='".$_REQUEST['password']."'";
$query = mysql_query($check);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows == 0)
{
echo "Invalid username/password";
}
else 
{
echo "login success";
}
}
?>
```

Echoed values are sent using the url
for eg: when logging success, values should be sent as "login success" but what actually happened is
"   login success      "

Comment: Do you have a leading space before `<?php` or such…?

Comment: BTW, you're open to SQL injection *and* you're storing passwords in plaintext. *Very frowny face :(((*

Comment: I have no leading space before.

Comment: can you give me detail about :                                                                    
SQL injection

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/476, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/476, [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/), https://stackoverflow.com/q/401656/476

Comment: thank you so much for that password protection.                                                                     can you help me out the solve above problem i am facing,why i am  getting that spaces

Comment: I think we should need some more code for your problem @anbu

Comment: i have post all code on that page , before few day the code worked fine i uploaded some other php files to server ,i got this problem in all the pages

Comment: Is there a space in `dbconn.php`, before `<?php`, or after `?>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if there are spaces or page breaks before php tag  (I mean at the start of the page). remove unwanted page breaks from the page (at the begining and in between)
For example:
before :

```
    if($numrows == 0)
{
echo "Invalid username/password";
}
```

mark as answer if this helps.

Comment: there is no spaces , the code format  passed above ,the same think i have in my side .

Comment: Are you sure that there are no page breaks before the start of file?

Comment: Check if the space issue occurs in case of invalid login.
The code seems alright.

Comment: thanks , i have spaces in "dbconfig " file ,thanks for solution given